# How to keep listening the S Pen detachment after the app gets closed from the Recent Apps list?

Tags: android, android-service, samsung-mobile

The goal is simple: to start an app when S Pen is detached. It is clear that it should be a service running even when the app is not running. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15199435/3214249) provides a good example of how to create a service to listen S Pen detachment by registering a receiver with BOOT_COMPLETED action. It does not matter whether you start your service from the app activity, or by registering a receiver - it works fine if you just "close" the app using Back button. But if you go to the list of recent apps and clear the app out of the list - the service stops and it does not work until you restart the device again. Does anyone have an idea how to keep listening the S Pen detachment even after the app was cleared out of the Recent Apps list?

Comment: "But if you go to the list of recent apps and clear the app out of the list - the service stops and it does not work" -- that is because your process was terminated.

Comment: So there is no way to listen such a system event (S Pen detachment in my case) and run an app that was entirely stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a Broadcast Receiver for `com.samsung.pen.INSERT` as described in this answer: [Bring your app to the front when S Pen detached in android note?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976198/bring-your-app-to-the-front-when-s-pen-detached-in-android-note/36223432#36223432)